# Refactoring big if else code

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have this really long if else code

```
 if (errorNumbers.Length == 6)
      {
        if (errorNumbers.Substring(0,4).Equals("1101") || errorNumbers.Substring(0,4).Equals("2121"))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterPickError";
        }
        else if (errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("1301") || errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("2321"))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterLAlignError";
        }
        else if (errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("1401") || errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("2221"))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError";
        }
        else if (errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("1501") || errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4).Equals("2041"))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery";
        }
```

etc.....

How I can rewrite it to something more nice .
Trying to learn here something new , and I am in .net 2.0.
Thanks for help.

Comment: First off, DRY Principle - Don't Repeat Yourself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  Assign the result of `errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4)` to a local variable.

Comment: You "could" use a strategy pattern but in most cases this is a complete overkill and sometimes difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I´d map the error codes in a dictionary like this:

```
string errorCode = errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4);
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string,string>();
map.Add("1501", "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery");
map.Add("2041", "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery");
map.Add("1401", "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError");
map.Add("2221", "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError");
map.Add("1301", "AutoRepickAfterPickError");
map.Add("2121", "AutoRepickAfterPickError");
// etc

if(!map.ContainsKey(errorCode))
 throw new Exception("Invalid error code");

return map[errorCode];
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the accepted, it´s actually more verbose and probably faster. I just dislike switches because of the extra code it adds.

Comment: well there is nothing "wrong" with it but a dictionary, preferably a static dictionary for something like this, is easier to maintain than switch statements.

Comment: Yes, that´s what i would´ve used aswell, which isn't very obvious in my example and therefor the accepted answer might be a bit more well described.

Comment: Performance with dictionary vs. switch is probably very similar since switch with string will probably use a hashtable in the background. But the two lookups in this sample instead of one (with e.g. TryGetValue) makes this a bit slower. Also it should be a cached static dictionary like @Yaur says. **IF** performance is important for this code...

Comment: Indeed, I utilized the ContainsKey to make the example more intuitive. And then with, 6-12 entries in the list, question is if it makes Any difference but keeping to practice is always good :)

Answer (score 11):

That should be pretty straightforward

```
if (errorNumbers.Length == 6)
{
    string errNo = errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4);

    switch (errNo)
    {
        case "1101":
        case "2121":
            retStr = "AutoRepickAfterPickError";
            break;
        case "1301":
        case "2321":
            retStr = "AutoRepickAfterLAlignError";
            break;
        case "1401":
        case "2221":
            retStr = "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError";
            break;
        case "1501":
        case "2041":
            retStr = "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery";
            break;
    }
}
```

Also note that unlike in Java, in C# you can compare strings with `==`.

`"123" == "456"` does the same thing as `"123".Equals("456")`.

Comment: The big IfElse / SwitchCase stay here

Answer (score 2):

First off, [DRY Principle - Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  Assign the result of `errorNumbers.Substring(0, 4)` to a local variable:

```
string subNumbers = errorNumbers.SubString(0, 4);
if (subNumbers == "1401") // ...
```

**Support for specific value cases (not ranges):**

You can use a switch statement with strings:

```
switch(subNumbers)
{
    case "1401":
    case "2221":
      retStr = "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError";
      break;
    case "1501":
    case "2041":
      retStr = "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery";
      break;
    // etc
}
```

An alternative to a switch statement is creating a dictionary:

```
var selections = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "1401", "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError" },
    { "2221", "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError" },
    { "1501", "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery" },
    { "2041", "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery" },
    // etc
};

if (selections.ContainsKey(subNumbers))
    retStr = selections[subNumbers];
```

**Ranges:**

If you need to support ranges, you're basically going to have to stick with the `if`/`else` blocks, though.  There are other options, but they tend to be too convoluted if you only have so many of these types of `if`/`else` blocks in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize a dictionary with refferencies betwen errorCode and errorMessage

```
Dictionary<int, string> errorsCache = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
  {1101,"AutoRepickAfterPickError"},
  {2121,"AutoRepickAfterPickError"},
  {1401,"AutoRepickAfterCAlignError"},
  ...
}
```

You can define GetErrorDescription method

```
public string GetErrorDescription(string errorNumbers)
{
  string retStr;
  if (errorNumbers.Length == 6)
  {
    int errorCode;  
    if(int.TryParse(errorNumbers.Substring(0,4), out errorCode))
    {
      errorsCache.TryGetValue(errorCode, out retStr);
    }
  }

  return retString;
  // or you can return empty string instead of null
  return retString ?? "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, store `errorNumbers.Substring(0,4)` in a local variable before the long if/else.

Then, you can eliminate the whole if/else using a map / dictionary from the expected error numbers to the appropriate return strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if (errorNumbers.Length == 6)
{

    //Makes it easier to change error codes, as theyre all in one place
    string[] AutoRepickAfterPickError = { "1101", "2121"};
    string[] AutoRepickAfterLAlignError = { "1301", "2321"};
    string[] AutoRepickAfterCAlignError = { "1401", "2221"};
    string[] AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery = { "1501", "2041"};
    string subString = errorNumbers.Substring(0,4);

        if (AutoRepickAfterPickError.Contains(subString));
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterPickError";
        }
        else if (AutoRepickAfterLAlignError.Contains(subString))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterLAlignError";
        }
        else if (AutoRepickAfterCAlignError.Contains(subString))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepickAfterCAlignError";
        }
        else if (AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery.Contains(subString))
        {
          retStr = "AutoRepicksAfterManualRecovery";
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What about Select-Case? :D

```
errorNumber = errorNumbers.Substring(0,4)
Select Case errorNumber 
   Case 1101,2121
      retStr = "AutoRepickAfterPickError";
   Case 1301,2321
      retStr = "AutoRepickAfterLAlignError";
   ...
End Select
```

Comment: This is a C# not VB.Net question.

Comment: Maybe better is delete answer